# Why use quien fuera instead of quien fue?

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-pasados

I just read the following article: https://actualidad.rt.com/actualidad/456511-alberto-fernandez-argentina-no-mandar-armamentos-ucrania

The last paragraph goes as follows:

Según fuentes familiarizadas con el asunto, el comandante del Ejército brasileño, Julio César de Arruda, quien fuera más tarde destituido, explicó a Lula que el Gobierno alemán pagaría algo menos de cinco millones de dólares por un lote de municiones para sus tanques Leopard-1. Sin embargo, el mandatario habría optado por rechazar la oferta, argumentando que "no valía la pena provocar a los rusos", afirma el periódico Folha de S.Paulo.

What bothers me is why they use the past subjunctive instead of "fue". And it's not the first time I come across such usage. Here's another example: https://actualidad.rt.com/actualidad/456421-pompeo-revela-eeuu-invadir-venezuela

El ministro de Defensa de Venezuela, Vladimir Padrino López, reaccionó este viernes a los testimonios divulgados esta semana por Mike Pompeo, quien fuera secretario de Estado de EE.UU. durante el gobierno de Donald Trump, donde confiesa los planes que pusieron en marcha y otros que contemplaron emprender contra el país suramericano, entre ellos un ataque militar.

What is going on?

Comment: Viktor, I have answered your question correctly, citing two experts on the issue. Please ignore the downvote.

Comment: In case of a downvoting attack, the system will solve it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/i-was-just-attacked-by-an-onslaught-of-downvotes-what-do-i-do

Comment: @Gustavson Well, it hasn't, has it? It's getting even worse: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19182/lambie?tab=reputation Glorfindel has escalated it.

Answer (score 2):

Cada lengua tiene sus propias características y otras costumbres que han ido evolucionando de forma dispar si las comparamos con otras. Por ello no debe molestarte que se utilice el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo en lugar, pues éste aparece normalmente en oraciones temporales y adjetivas sustituyendo al pretérito **pluscuamperfecto de indicativo** (había sido) y **al pretérito perfecto simple** (fue).

El pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo es el tiempo más complejo del modo subjuntivo, tanto por los contextos sintácticos en los que se usa como por la variedad de los significados que expresa.

En español, el pretérito imperfecto del modo subjuntivo es un tiempo que puede tener sentido tanto para expresar o referirse al pasado, al presente o al futuro.

Ejemplos con el pretérito imperfecto en modo subjuntivo que tienen este valor temporal:

**Presente** ¿Estas libre? Me gustaría que **quedáramos** para tomar algo.

**Pasado** Ayer te mande un mensaje porque quería que me **ayudaras**.

**Futuro** ¿Qué haces mañana? Me gustaría que **fuéramos** al cine.

El antiguo valor etimológico bajo las formas latinas "**AMAVERAM**", "**AMAVISSEM**" se emplea cada vez menos en la literatura creativa, pero se sigue utilizando en redacciones de periódicos y emisoras de radio y televisión, donde se la considera más elegante.

Ejemplos;

- Es opinión del que una vez **fuera** presidente de la Junta de Andalucía.
- La que **fuera** la primera mujer en dirigir un semanario francés confiesa que no puede evitar que todo lo humano y lo divino le interese.
- La que **fuera** primera ministra del Reino Unido, apodada "La Dama de Hierro"...

En estos últimos casos se suele utilizar la forma "**fuera**" ya que se considera una manera más arcaica y elegante de escribir a la vez que denota cierta cortesía.

Comment: Diego, estoy un poco molesta con todo lo que veo aqui hoy. Digo, un mal comportamiento. Hoy, alguien me está poniendo votos menos sistematicamente en español, puede contar menos 10!. Respondí a la pregunta que se trata de periodismo. No sé como esta gente se justifica, francamente.

Comment: @Lambie Estoy contigo. En ocasiones me han quitado puntos sin justificación aparente o recibido una cascada de puntos negativos en cuestiones que realmente no las merecían. A veces pienso que el tiempo ha formado una especie de bloques, grupos de apoyo  o usuarios reconocidos, que por alguna razón prefieren votarse entre sí y dejan fuera o votan en contra de personas que sencillamente no pertenecen a ese círculo, actuando inexplicablemente con ojeriza hacia ellos a pesar de que su respuesta sea correcta. Lo único que puedo hacer es ayudarte con puntos positivos allá donde sea injustificable.

Comment: Te agradezco por lo que dices. Es como recibir una paliza. Si fuera moderadora, pondría un comentário en mi respuesta. Pero bueno, no lo soy. El otro dia un participante hizo un comentário diciendo que soy "viejo" (man) e algo como "slow mind". Increíble, ¿no? Te lo pongo para que lo veas de tus proprios ojos: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19182/lambie?tab=reputation

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene 10 votos positivos en la lista que acabo de darte. Sin embargo, aparece aqui como -1. Estraño...

Comment: Diego, me parece que solo "fuera" se puede usar en este caso, no "fuese".

Comment: @Gustavson hola! Me surgió la duda cuando lo comentaste. Al menos en España se suele escuchar de vez en cuando, aunque lo más frecuente es "fuera", otra cosa es que sin querer o por desconocimiento, "fuese" este mal dicho o no se deba decir. Intente buscar alguna regla en este sentido, pero no hallé nada. Al ser más bien una expresión que se escucha oralmente, es difícil verla escrita. Arriba al final te puse un ejemplo que encontré. No obstante, si sabes que consta realmente en algún lado, por favor dímelo para añadirlo y modificar el artículo. Gracias por el comentario y un saludo.

Comment: @Lambie cuando te suceda una cosa así utiliza la bandera para contactar  con el moderador y comentar las salidas de tono o falta de respeto por parte de algunos usuarios. Si decides presentarte para moderadora cuenta con mi voto. Después del comentario recibí algún voto negativo por parte de alguien, aunque imagino quien fue, por lo visto no le agrado lo que te dije. "Esta pregunta tiene 10 votos positivos en la lista que acabo de darte. Sin embargo, aparece aquí como -1". Es porque antes tenías -2 votos en contra y cada voto corresponde a 10 puntos, aunque por cada nuevo voto  recuperas 8 pt.

Comment: En este sitio: http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/imperfecto%20subjuntivo%20literario.htm Manuel Seco, el famoso catedrático, desaconseja ambas formas, pero dice que "fuese" es peor: Más raro y más rechazable es el empleo de la forma –se con el mismo valor de pretérito indefinido

Comment: @Diego, la bandera donde? En que lugar? Tiendria que ponerlo en un comentário y no sé de quien vino. //Mi respuesta tiene un profesor de periodismo hablando de este tema, y nadie lo comentó en positivo. No entiendo.

Comment: Creo que te dispersas demasiado en la respuesta, hasta el punto de que no queda demasiado clara. Creo que deberías ir más al grano y responder a la pregunta de manera más clara y directa

Comment: @FGSUZ Gracias por tu comentario, intentaré mejorar.

Comment: @Diego, el futuro en subjuntivo de ir (según el DLE, aunque suena raro) es *fuéremos*

Comment: @VeAqui Hola, gracias por el comentario, llevas toda la razón. Sin embargo, me refería al distinto valor que en español puede expresar el pretérito imperfecto en modo subjuntivo, que es un tiempo que en su uso, se puede hallar tanto para hacer referencias al pasado, al presente o al futuro. Yo creo que el enunciado anterior a los ejemplos lo deja claro, pero si crees que es confuso, me dices y lo cambio, no hay problema. Así, en este caso tanto, "quedáramos", "ayudaras" y "fuéramos", son pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo que tienen en el ejemplo esta característica temporal. Saludos

Comment: @VeAqui No obstante, lo cambie a ver si así, esa parte, te resulta más comprensible. Gracias.

Comment: Hombre, la pregunta es muy precisa y no pide una explicacíon de todos estos tiempos de los verbos, siino porque se utliza **fuera** en vez de **fue**, en la escritura periodística. Me parece injusto que a nadie le gustó mi respuesta con explicación de dos expertos en la materia....

Answer (score -1):

It is used in news writing as explained in this Instituto Cervantes post:

> Otro ejemplo, este también de la prensa: «Es opinión del que fuera
> presidente de la nación» (la forma absolutamente correcta sería "fue",
> pero han usado "fuera" con ese mismo valor temporal del lat.: "había
> sido")
> [...]
> El imperfecto de subjuntivo -que procede del pretérito
> pluscuamperfecto de indicativo latino- se utiliza sobre todo en
> periodismo y en lenguaje literario porque conserva en parte ese mismo
> valor latino (castellano: "había imaginado"), sin que el hablante sea
> consciente de ello.

Autor: Luisa Seoane Rey
Título: *El imperfecto de subjuntivo en castellano*
Fecha y hora: martes, 5 de marzo de 2019

[foros del Instituto Cervantes](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=55079)

In other words, *fuera* there stands in for had been (habia sido).

Here's another reference:

> c) Imperfecto de subjuntivo
>
> El uso del pretérito imperfecto de
> subjuntivo, especialmente en su variante con la terminación en -ra,
> con un valor temporal de pasado –bien de pluscuamperfecto, bien de
> perfecto simple–, **es uno de los rasgos identificativos del lenguaje
> periodístico, pues apenas se encuentran ejemplos de ello en otras
> tipologías textuales:** El 1 de julio de 2005, el que fuera rector de la
> uji acordó la liquidación definitiva de las obras (abc, 20/09/2011).
> La teoría más plausible es que el robo se produjera el mismo viernes
> día 9 (El Mundo, 17/09/2011). Desde que comenzaran las protestas en
> marzo pasado, al menos 2035 civiles y 477 miembros de las fuerzas de
> seguridad han muerto en las revueltas (abc, 8/09/2011). Barack Obama
> será hoy el primer presidente de ee uu que visite Puerto Rico desde
> que John Kennedy lo hiciera hace 50 años (El País, 14/06/2011).
>
> Una de las dos principales hipótesis con las que trabaja la Policía
> Científica es que el marido matara a su esposa y a la niña, y luego se
> quitara la vida (abc, 13/04/2010). Todos los manuales de estilo
> condenan su uso, pese a que la mayoría reconocen que no se trata de
> una incorrección, sino de una cuestión de carácter estilístico. Así,
> el de abc lo considera «arcaico y artificioso [...], alejado de la
> lengua estándar» (2001: 119); en similares términos se expresa el de
> El País, que añade el calificativo de «pretencioso» (2002: 420). El
> manual de Canal Sur concluye: «conviene no abusar de él» porque, a
> pesar de ser correcto,«se aleja del modo de hablar en español» (2004:
> 211).
>
> Curiosamente, esta derivación temporal del imperfecto de subjuntivo
> recupera su origen etimológico, como reconoce el manual de Fundéu
> (2008: 78), a través de un recorrido histórico que recuerda la
> procedencia de las formas en -ra del pluscuamperfecto latino, lo que
> perpetuó ese valor a lo largo de las diferentes épocas de la lengua.
> La pervivencia de este uso en la práctica periodística, a pesar de la
> mencionada opinión contraria de los manuales, lleva a pensar en la
> evidencia de un estilo de escritura periodístico, plenamente
> consolidado y vertebrado a través de las rutinas profesionales, que
> legitima unos modelos de actuación lingüística más allá de las
> presiones normativas, externas e internas.

**Lengua española para comunicadores (Periodismo) - UJI -** DOI:

http://[dx.doi.org/10.6035/Sapientia92](https://dx.doi.org/10.6035/Sapientia92)

Comment: Downvoter: This answer is exactly right. There is no other explanation. Also, the Instituto Cervantes is the TOP Spanish teaching and learning institution for Spanish. You really should not have downvoted this answer.

Comment: This now has four downvotes and two upvotes. People should be ashamed. Really.